# Magento EM Quickshop quickview fancybox https and parent window http fix

Tags: jquery, magento, https, fancybox

Magento EM Quickshop fancybox works but the fancybox will not close automatically (after putting the product in the shopping cart) and I can't update the shopping cart in the parent window with ajax (so a customer has to do a refresh of the parent window).

What is the problem ?

With debugging when closing the fancybox I get: Permission denied to access property 'jQuery'.

When the fancybox or boxes are created in JQuery the url's start with http, I checked that with debugging in firefox.

But when I display the url in the fancybox (by clicking on a link that opens the fancybox, type iFrame) with document.URL it starts with https. And because a https window can not communicate with a http parent (access denied), the fancybox don't close.

My question: have somebody an idea how and where the http can change meanwhile to https ?

Or how can you check while debugging that a definition (url) of a fancybox changes somewhere ?

Or can there be somewhere a setting that javascript forces to SSL ?

Comment: No it was another problem. The url inside the fancybox is redirected to https (just a product url), and that gives this problem. Why I have still to find ... It even happens when I switch off SSL in Magento for the front-end ...

Comment: All links started with quickshop are redirected to htpps like 'h t t p://www.etc/index.php/quickshop/..' or 'h t t p://www.etc/quickshop/...'

Comment: See the answer in this post
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28992600/em-quickshop-http-and-https-issues/30540271#30540271][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28992600/em-quickshop-http-and-https-issues/30540271#30540271

Answer (score 0):

The solution. This all was done by others because the add to shopping cart in an iframe is only possible for this customer by using https, so all links are redirected to https. By using document.location for a http page, I can communicate within that page with the http parent window. By using parameters in the url I can transmit the result sidebox shopping cart to the parent window. So I have now the situation created unless the parent window is http, the iframe is https, with the aid of document.location I can close the fancybox (iframe) automatically and update the shopping cart of the parent window without a refresh by using jquery. This all is working normally ok when both windows have the same protocol (http), but that is not my case.

Comment: A better solution is just creating an extra controller action for retrieving the html for the sidebox shopping cart. Parameters are not needed anymore (I got problems with the length of the parameters and when I was even trying to do it with an extra database file for the parameters, I got problems with that length in updating the database file, all has to do with memory).