# Em Quickshop http and https issues

Tags: magento

I am using Em Quickshop and it's working fine with http or https separately.

When I am using http and https together, then Quickshop gives me an error like "the contents of this website is not secure" and I just get a blank page.

I am using Magento 1.9.1.

Answer (score 0):

This problem arrives because of magento create a stack of `HTTPs urls` usually all admin `URLs` add to this stack.
To resolve issue of redirection to `HTTPS` instead of `HTTP`, you need to change `frontName` of the `EM_Quickshop` module

```
/app/code/community/EM/Quickshop/etc/config.xml
```

change the `frontName` of admin section from `<frontName>quickshop</frontName>` to

```
<frontName>quick_shp</frontName>
<admin>
        <routers>
            <quickshop>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>EM_Quickshop</module>
                    <frontName>quick_shp</frontName>
                </args>
            </quickshop>
        </routers>
    </admin>
```